# Facebook / twitter links not working in ios ionic App

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

iam creating an ionic ios app, i added linkto  many urls(facebook,twitter, apple store) but its not working.

I set  in allow-navigation config.xml

```
<allow-navigation href="https://www.facebook.com/diethelpweight" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

This is the way i created links

```
<div class="social-share">
    <div class="social-share-inner">

        <div class="share-img-div"><!-- <img src="img/button/fb.png"> <i class="ion-social-facebook" ng-click=" window.open('https://www.facebook.com/diethelpweight', '_system', 'location=yes');"></i></div>
        <div class="share-img-div"><!-- <img src="img/button/twitter.png"> --><i class="ion-social-googleplus" ng-click="openBrowser('https://plus.google.com/u/3/+Weightlossdiethelp101')"></i></div>
        <div class="share-img-div"><!-- <img src="img/button/g+.png"> --><i class="ion-social-twitter" ng-click="openBrowser('https://twitter.com/DietHelpWeight')"></i></div>
        <div class="share-img-div"><!-- <img src="img/button/pinterest.png"> --><i class="ion-social-pinterest" ng-click="openBrowser('http://www.pinterest.com/diethelpweightl')"></i></div>
        <div class="share-img-div"><!-- <img src="img/button/youtube.png"> --><i class="ion-social-instagram" ng-click="openBrowser('http://instagram.com/weightloss_diethelp')"></i></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

but its not working, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you show or at least tell us what the `openBrowser()` function does?

Comment: @Dexter to open that link in browser of ios device

Comment: Check mention below answer.it may helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36741097/timeline-with-dynamic-search-query-ionic/37551191#37551191[enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36741097/timeline-with-dynamic-search-query-ionic/37551191#37551191)

Answer (score 0):

I think these lines are not accepted by ios;

```
<allow-intent href="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

You should write each domain seperately such as

```
<allow-navigation href="http://www.facebook.com/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://www.facebook.com/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://m.facebook.com/*" />

<allow-navigation href="https://embed.spotify.com/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://open.spotify.com/*" />
```

and if your openBrowser function checks for a native app is installed or not you should tell it in the info.plist file like these lines jus because ios rules are changed for checking an is installed or not.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>twitter</string>
        <string>fb</string>
        <string>youtube</string>
        <string>instagram</string>
    </array>
```

Comment: in IOS links are get fired, when i am removing fullscreen i.e go to show all app