# Timeline with dynamic search query (Ionic)

Tags: twitter, ionic-framework, timeline, hashtag

Twitter gives the possibility to create a timeline widget from a specific query and id. I'm developping an Ionic Cordova app and I want to create timeline with the query search given by the user (from an input for example). Is that possible?

When I test the Twitter widget timeline in my device, the button event (like, retweet...) doesn't work. Can anyone please explain me why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First check ngcordova and ng-cordova-oauth is installed proper or not. you can use steps of [Adding google plus login to ionic app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37523038/adding-google-plus-login-to-ionic-app/37525072#37525072)

than use ionic serve. click on your login button. it will give error "Cannot authenticate via a web browser". it confirmed that you ngCordova and ng-cordova-auth working perfect.

**Note:- its working in Devices only**